# Slice a string and store it as list in django python inside HTML file

Tags: python, html, django, python-3.x

I am sending a variable **names** = "['name1', 'name2', 'name3']" as String to an HTML file from my method in views.py along with other information.

When I tried to split the string **names** with **names.split()** as:

```
{% for name in names.split(',') %}
 {{ name }}
{% endfor %}
```

then I am facing this TemplateSyntaxError

> Could not parse the remainder: '(',')' from
>   'share.share_per_person.split(',')'

When I tried to print the string as

```
{{ names }}
```

then output is 
    *['name1', 'name2', 'name3']*

I want to display individual names on screen.

Comment: Can you explain why you are sending this string that looks like a list in the first place? Where did you get it from? And why can't you do this conversion in the view?

Comment: Why don't you render `template` with `render()` method  with `context` , so you can easily loop through it ?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I am getting this data from local Database in which I used a column "names" to store list of names as a string in database.

Comment: @VuHuuCuong I used render from my view to call html file as
return render(request, 'app/main.html', {'names': names}).
Is this what you asked? I dont have knowledge on what a context is.

Comment: Convert to a proper list in the view. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1894293/4872140 for how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use something like the following in your view to convert that string from your database to a proper list using [abstract syntax tree](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/ast.html) method literal_eval.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import ast

def sample_request(request):

    names = "['name1', 'name2', 'name3']"

    # abstract syntax tree
    # https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/ast.html
    names_list = ast.literal_eval(names)

    context = {'names': names_list,
               'some_other_var': 'value',
               }
    return render(request, 'dashboard/index.html', context)
```

then in your template you should be able to do the normal 

`{% for name in names %}
  {{ name }}<br />
{% endfor %}`

credit to https://stackoverflow.com/a/1894293/4872140